# Custom tableViewCell displays incorrectly when scrolled

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview populated with an array of names and images. I’ve added a custom cell by subclassing UITableViewCell. The custom cell contains a UIImage that has the mode set to “Aspect Fill” and the height and width set to 52 to fit neatly into my custom cell. When I run the application it loads all the images and correctly fits them into my container view at the dimensions I’ve specified. The problem is whenever I scroll the view, the reused cells displays the images as if I did not have a custom cell. In other words, incorrectly. Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    contact = contactsArray[indexPath.row];
    NSString *firstName = contact[@"mutableFirstName"];
    NSString *lastName = contact[@"mutableLastName"];
    UIImage *image = contact[@"mutableImage"];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    cell.firstNameLabel.text = firstName;
    cell.lastNameLabel.text = lastName;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you using story board?

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboard

Comment: Then set "Cell" as cell identifier

Comment: I've done that as well.

Comment: same case remember device is case sensitive and simulator is not

Comment: Actually, I believe you meant set cell identifier, which I have and it is set to "Cell"

Comment: I might add that the labels that I've added to my custom cell are displaying exactly right. It just the image that gets hosed up. So my cell id is correct.

Comment: are you using autolayout on storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I am using auto layout. I turned it off, and then when the app first loads the images are not displayed correctly. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

What if, if your 
`customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];`
returns `nil` ...???

Modify your implementation as :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[customCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = image;
    cell.firstNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", contact[@"mutableFirstName"]];
    cell.lastNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", contact[@"mutableImage"]];
    return cell;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I turned off Auto Layout and that seems to fix the problem. Regarding Balram's recommendation, it is my understanding that when using storyboards, adding an "if statement" to determine if a cell exists is unnecessary. Is that correct?

Comment: In addition to my answer above, I resized all the images down to a more manageable size. That might have been my ultimate problem all along. Thanks everyone.